# MFC: What method is used to set the toolbar buttons to be a subset of the total toolbar buttons by default?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cmfctoolbar

I want to add all `menu items` to the `toolbar` but only have a subset of them showing by default (without user having to customize). This way all menu items will have icons next to them, but the toolbar won't contain the seldom used items unless users adds them.

If possible, how is that done with `CMFCToolBar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If possible, how is that done with CMFCToolBar?*

You can define any number of 'dummy' toolbar resources in your program's resource script, like the below example, where `ID_DUMMY1` is the toolbar/bitmap resource ID (*must* be available to both the resource compiler *and* the C++ compiler) and the three `ID_COMMAND_x` IDs define the menu commands that the images correspond to:

```
ID_DUMMY1 BITMAP   L"DummyToolbar.bmp" // 16 x 48 bitmap for three 'buttons
ID_DUMMY1 TOOLBAR  16, 16
{
    BUTTON    ID_COMMAND_A // Three commands corresponding to the three button
    BUTTON    ID_COMMAND_B // images in the above bitmap
    BUTTON    ID_COMMAND_C
}
```

Then, in your program (typically, just after you have initialized your main frame window), you can call the *static* member of the `CMFCToolBar` class, [`AddToolBarForImageCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbar-class?view=vs-2019#addtoolbarforimagecollection) to load the images from those dummy toolbars. The following will load those image in the above-defined resource:

```cpp
    CMFCToolBar::AddToolBarForImageCollection(ID_DUMMY1, ID_DUMMY1);
```

After this, every menu item with the given command(s) will show the associated image as defined in the dummy toolbar resource(s). You can have as many such toolbar resources as required, and just call the `AddToolBarForImageCollection` for each one.

---

Note: Although I have used the *same* resource ID for both toolbar and bitmap resources, you can also use *different* IDs. So long as the arguments given in the call to `AddToolBarForImageCollection` are properly coordinated, the method will still work.

Comment: This is great, but I didn't see a way to add the large icons as well.  Is there an Ex version that includes those?